# Exception in exporting to excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, exception

Using c#.net I am exporting data from labels in my form to excel. The code is as follows:

```
Excel.Font font = range.Font;
 font.Color =Color.Black;
```

While using this code, I am getting an exception

"Methods with System.Color parameters or return type cannot be invoked via IDispatch".

Please help me solve this.

Comment: Actually you need to show more of the code. What is definition for `Excel`? `range`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you will find the answer in the following thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbinterop/thread/6a25be14-fc4f-40c6-aaea-62cb76140cd1/

Quick answer:

```
     font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Black)
```